# Cat with Headers and Line Numbers?

Tags: cat

I have files like this

```
$ cat trapetz
x = 0:0.0001:7pi
plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
$ cat simpson 
f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
```

I want something like this

```
$ cat -b -t MISSING? trapetz simpson 
     traapetz 
     1  x = 0:0.0001:7pi
     2  plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     3  Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     simpson
     1  f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
     2  Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
```

or even better if some easy way to add wc there:

```
$ find |tee |...|wc... I feel now reinventing the wheel, there must be some ready...
     traapetz: xyz chars
     1  x = 0:0.0001:7pi
     2  plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     3  Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     simpson: zyx chars
     1  f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
     2  Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
```

but I get

```
$ cat -b -t trapetz simpson 
     1  x = 0:0.0001:7pi
     2  plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     3  Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     4  f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
     5  Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
```

Not really cat needed but some easy tool to share and show code snippets like the above, not pastebin. I want some standard command line thing. I am trying to create easy puzzle -pasting for codegolf.se so people could reproduce things easily...

Comment: see also [cat files with directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46524)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very rough awk implementation:

```
BEGIN{
    OLDFILENAME="";
}
FNR==1{
    if (OLDFILENAME != "") {
        printf("#### Processed (chars: %s - lines: %s)\n", FWC, FLC);
    }
    printf("#### Processing: %s\n", FILENAME);
    OLDFILENAME=FILENAME;
    FWC=0;
    FLC=0;
}
{
    printf("%04d - %s\n", FNR, $0);
    FWC = FWC + length($0);
    FLC = FLC + 1;
}
END{
    if (OLDFILENAME != "") {
        printf("#### Processed (chars: %s - lines: %s)\n", FWC, FLC);
    }
}
```

Execute `awk -f AWKFILE trapetz simpson` to get:

```
#### Processing: trapetz
0001 - x = 0:0.0001:7pi
0002 - plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
0003 - Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
#### Processed (chars: 70 - lines: 3)
#### Processing: simpson
0001 - f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
0002 - Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
#### Processed (chars: 57 - lines: 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Quick shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: scriptname file1 file2 ...

for file in "$@"
do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    set -- `wc "$file"`
    echo "${file}: lines $1 words $2 bytes $3"
    cat -b -t "$file"
done
```

It behaves like your sample output, so missing files are silently ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`tail -n +1 trapetz simpson` will print each file with a leading header giving the file name. `nl trapetz simpson` prints line numbers but no file names. You'll need to use either [`awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23528/cat-with-headers-and-line-numbers/23530#23530) or some shell glue to combine the two.

```
for x in trapetz simpson; do
  echo "$x: $(wc -c <"$x") bytes"
  nl "$x"
done
```

Here's an awk solution which prints the byte count at the bottom:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {print "end", fn, chars, "characters"; bytes=0}
    END {print "end", fn, chars, "characters"}
    FNR == 1 {print "begin", FILENAME; fn=FILENAME}
    1 {chars += 1 + length; printf "%7d ", FNR; print}
' trapetz simpson
```

Comment: Line `FNR == 1 && NR != 1...` prints the wrong filename...    and it counts characters, not bytes (re non ASCII text)

Comment: BTW, `tail -n +1 *` will print each file with a leading header (formatted as “==> %s <==”) *if there is more than one file.*  (If there is only one file, it basically acts like `cat`.)  You can request the headers with `-v`. Also, it prints blank lines between the files, which increases readability but may be undesirable if the user specifically wants the output formatted as shown. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Also, isn’t “leading header” redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Here is `sed` + `wc` + `nl` + `cat` (and a `bash` loop)

```
set trapetz simpson
for file in "$@" ;do
  { wc -l -m "$file"; cat "$file"; } | 
    sed -nr '1{N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\x01\1/};p' | nl |
    sed -r '1{s/(.*)\x01 *([0-9]+) +([0-9]+) (.*)$/\4  (\2 lines, \3 chars)\n\1/};$s/.*/&\n/' 
done; echo "(${#@} files)"
```

Output

```
trapetz  (3 lines, 73 chars)
     1  x = 0:0.0001:7pi
     2  plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     3  Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))

simpson  (2 lines, 59 chars)
     1  f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
     2  Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
  
(2 files)
```

---

Here is `sed` + `grep` (no *wc* though).

Using `sed` for situations such as this is  good for *regex* and sed juggling practice, but when the juggling gets to be too much, the ability to use a single tool (eg. `awk`) is ususlly the better option..

```
grep -nH '.' trapetz simpson | sed -nre 'G; s/^([^:]+):.*\n\1/&/; tp; h; s/^([^:]+).*/\1/p; g; :p; s/^[^:]+:([^:]+):(.*)\n.*/0000\1  \2/; s/^[^ ]*([^ ]{4})(.*)/\1\2/p; g; s/^([^:]+).*/\1/; h'
```

Or a more readable representation :)

```
grep -nH '.' trapetz simpson |
  sed -nre '
  G                      # pattern+=nl+hold
  s/^([^:]+):.*\n\1/&/   # if
      t printline        # when prev==curr branch to printline   
  : new_file             # when prev!=curr print header
      h                  # hold the pattern  
      s/^([^:]+).*/\1/p  # print header (filename)
      g                  # get the held pattern 
  : printline            # print current line (with line number) 
      s/^[^:]+:([^:]+):(.*)\n.*/0000\1  \2/   # zero pad number  
      s/^[^ ]*([^ ]{4})(.*)/\1\2/p            # number width = 4
      g                  # get the held pattern 
      s/^([^:]+).*/\1/   # extract filename
      h                  # hold the filename
'
```

Output

```
trapetz
0001  x = 0:0.0001:7pi
0002  plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
0003  Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
simpson
0001  f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
0002  Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
```

Answer (score 0):

This command list:

```
echo -e "trapetz\nsimpson" | xargs -I fn sh -c "wc -c fn | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2: \1 chars/';cat -b -t fn"
```

Produces this output

```
trapetz: 73 chars
     1  x = 0:0.0001:7pi
     2  plot(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
     3  Area = trapz(x, sin(x).*cos(x))
simpson: 59 chars
     1  f = inline(sin(x).*cos(x));
     2  Area2 = quad(f, 0, 7pi, 1e-16)
```

Software versions are:

- bash 4.2.53
- GNU sed 4.2.2
- xargs 4.5.11
- cat 8.21