# Displaying file names with contents when using the "cat" command

Tags: filenames, cat

Is there a command to show the directory or file name when using `cat` to display the contents of files?

For example: assume two files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` are in `./tmp`

```
./tmp/f1.txt
./tmp/f2.txt
```

Then when I do `cat ./tmp/*.txt`, only the content of the files will be shown. But how to first show the file name, then the content? e.g.:

```
 (The needed command):
 ./tmp/f1.txt:  
 This is from f1.txt
 and so on
 ./tmp/f2.txt:
 This is from f2.txt ...
```

Is there a command to do it? (There seems to be no option for `cat` to show the file names.)

Comment: See also [Cat with Headers and Line Numbers?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23528)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ for file in ./tmp/*.txt; do printf '%s\n' "$file";  cat "$file"; done
```

-or-

```
$ find ./tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -print -exec cat "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 36):

Just as another idea, try `tail -n +1 ./tmp/*.txt`

```
==> ./tmp/file1.txt <==
<contents of file1.txt>

==> ./tmp/file2.txt <==
<contents of file2.txt>

==> ./tmp/file3.txt <==
<contents of file3.txt>
```

Comment: This is nice, but how to display the filename if there is only one file?

Comment: @mvorisek, with the GNU implementation of `tail` at least, you'd use the `-v` option for that.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you can *prefix each line* with the filename:

```
$ grep '^' ./tmp/*.txt
./tmp/f1.txt: this is from f1.txt
./tmp/f1.txt: blaa, blaa, blaa...
./tmp/f1.txt: blaa, blaa, blaa...
./tmp/f2.txt: this is from f2.txt
./tmp/f2.txt: blaa, blaa, blaa...
./tmp/f2.txt: blaa, blaa, blaa...
```

It will be tough to do much better than this without resorting to a little scripting.

Comment: That is a good workaround - my files are actually single line.

Comment: This would not output any filenames if the glob matches only a single file.

Answer (score 4):

Not enough reputation point to add a comment to second [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46530/175520)

```
tail -v -n +1 /tmp/*.txt
```

will display filename even if there is only one file.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily write a tiny script doing just that,

```
for f in "$@" do; echo "This is from $f"; cat -- "$f"; done
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to avoid using script - by using a command?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is not such a command

Comment: What is the practical difference between a script and a command, or, why does it matter that multiple commands are entered on a single command-line to solve the problem?  The command doesn't have to be in a file.  You can run the "script" by just typing in the text given.

Comment: That is true - but i want to use something existed, please see the answer from  "ire_and_curses" and "kbulgrien"

Comment: Hello, i typed the given text in the command line of my terminal and it says: "syntax error near unexpected token echo". why does it happen?

Comment: @lukmac: Try something more like this: `for f in *; do echo "This is from ${f}"; cat $f; done`

Comment: Please use `"$@"` instead of `$*`, as the former will handle filenames with spaces (this is part of POSIX shell, it's *not* a bash-ism). Also, `cat "$f"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep . *.txt
```

Matches all lines and also shows file names

Comment: `.` doesn't match empty lines

Comment: Only shows filenames if there are more than a single file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*' -execdir cat '{}' \;
```

When a directory is passed to `cat`, you'll see something like:

```
cat: ./chapter_01: Is a directory
```

Immediately following, the `find` will `cat` the contents of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

cat is (intentionally) an extremely simple command that just reads one file stream and dumps it to another (with a few basic formatting options). It'd be fairly easy to create a utility based on cat that did provide the filename, but standard versions won't do this -- probably because it's easy to replicate with other commands.

If you want to examine the pages manually you could use 'less'. This will give you the filename at the end of every file, in the format: 'foo.txt (file 1 of 100) (END) - Next: bar.txt).

Answer (score 0):

More gives nice headings, poor cat though:

```
$ more *.txt | cat
::::::::::::::
file1.txt
::::::::::::::
line1
line2

::::::::::::::
file2.txt
::::::::::::::
line1
line2
line3
```

...and so on.