# how do I output multiple files with a heading for each one but without needing to page through them?

Tags: cat, xargs, more

I am running a file search command with `ag -g foo` and I'd like to see the contents of the files I find.

If I do `ag -g foo | xargs more` then the `more` command makes me press the spacebar to advance between each file, even though they are small enough that I could see more than one at a time in my terminal window.

If I do `ag -g foo | xargs cat` then I see everything at once, but the files are mushed together so it's hard to see where a new file starts.

Is there a way to see the files all in one scroll, but with a heading for each one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cat files with directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46524/cat-files-with-directory). In other words, `ag -g foo | xargs tail -n+1`.

Comment: Similar: [Cat all files in a folder including filename by using a for loop?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/256300)

Comment: @Quasímodo yes, your solution produces very nice output! Fiddly to type, but I can make an alias! :) Please post as an answer if you like!

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Nevermind that, I prefer that this becomes a duplicate and then people can go to the answer I have pointed you and upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could tell `xargs` to add a header:

```
ag -g foo | xargs sh -c '
    for file do
        printf "====== %s =====\n" "$file"
        cat -- "$file"
    done' sh
```

Or, you could use a loop:

```
ag -g foo | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do 
        printf '======== %s =======\n' "$file" 
        cat -- "$file"
    done | less
```

(here assuming `ag` outputs one filename per line as opposed to in the very specific format expected by `xargs`).

Comment: See also the `-t` (trace) option of `xargs`.